# Dividing custom spring-boot-starter into several modules

Tags: module, dependencies, pom.xml, spring-boot-starter

I am developing my own spring-boot-starter. I have read advice that the best practice will be to divide starter into two modules: the first module with business logic that does not provide any beans and the another module with autoconfiguration that creates beans from the classes from the module with business logic. Then the second module with autoconfiguration are included in the target app.

Are there any advantages of that approach? Why is it better than organize the spring-boot-starter in the one solid module?